# Wijmo Debug Options

Tags: javascript, componentone

When using a ComponentOne control (ex: LineChart, Slider) you can pass in a number of options.  Using FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools, how can I access the options for a control?  If I change a value, what do I need to do to have the change reflected on the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the options during debugging by using your selector in the following jQuery:

$("#wijlinechart").data("wijlinechart").options